# Does Factor have multiline shebangs?

Tags: multiline, getopt, shebang, factor-lang

Common Lisp has multiline shebangs:

```
#!/bin/bash
#|
exec clisp -q -q $0 $0 ${1+"$@"}
exit
|#
```

This allows more complex operations within a shebang. CLISP is one of the few languages that omits the script name from ARGV. Here, the script name is forcibly sent twice to CLISP so that the Lisp script can access its script name via ARGV.

Is there a way to do this in Factor so that the following works?

```
$ cat ios7crypt.factor 
#! /usr/bin/env factor

USING: kernel namespaces io prettyprint ;
IN: ios7crypt

: usage ( -- )
    "Usage: ios7crypt.factor [options]" print
    "-encrypt <password>" print
    "-decrypt <hash>" print
    "-test" print
    "-help" print ;

: main ( -- ) "help" get . ;

MAIN: main

$ ./ios7crypt.factor
f

$ ./ios7crypt.factor -help
f
```

The above line should print `t`, but Factor ignores `-help` because it came after the script name.

```
$ factor ios7crypt.factor 
f

$ factor -help ios7crypt.factor 
t
```

This works because `-help` was sent before the script name. `./ios7crypt.factor -help` silently drops `-help` because the shebang expands to `factor ios7crypt.factor -help`. Unfortunately, Factor seems to require all command line options before the script name.

Is there a multiline shebang overriding this behavior?

Comment: It's not like "Common Lisp has multi-line shebangs". What you posted is a Bash script which runs Common Lisp on itself. Perhaps something like that could be done in Factor too (I'm not familiar with the language) if you can come up with a Bash script which is syntactically a comment, or orherwise somehow a no-op in Factor's view.

Comment: Actually, yeah, Common Lisp does have multiline shebangs. This is because Common Lisp has `#| ... |#` syntax.

Comment: still, that's not part of the shebang line.  Again, that is a Bash script whose beginning is "invisible" to Common Lisp, and whose end is "invisible" to Bash because Bash executes Common Lisp on the file, then exits.  Sure, the existence of that particular syntax in Common Lisp helps, but it's still not a shebang.

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like `: ignore ( -- ); exec /usr/bin/env factor --options` but I have no idea what that means to Factor, if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line options sent to a script are not automatically parsed. One must manually send them to the parser.

```
$ cat args.factor 
#! /usr/bin/env factor

USING: namespaces command-line prettyprint ;
IN: args

: main ( -- )
    command-line get parse-command-line
    "a" get .
    "b" get .
    "c" get .
    ;

MAIN: main
```

Example:

```
$ ./args.factor -a -b=banana
t
"banana"
f
```